# DHTML newbie question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started learning Javascript and I am absolutely overwhelmed with the number of technologies available especially on the browser side. Earlier I thought that just Javascript should suffice but now it appears that I need to understand JQuery, GWT, YUI and another dozen acronyms I do not even know the expansion for. Can somebody please tell me which are the most essential technologies one needs to be fluent with in this domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually go with [standard JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference) unless I need to modify the [DOM](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) or [attach events](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html). In those cases, [each browser has its own way of doing things](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) and then it's much simpler to use a well-tested framework.

Right now, I've found that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is the most light-weight and intuitive choice if all you want is the ability to control the DOM. For everything else, I write my own code.

Just don't use more than one framework or it'll get messy.

Comment: +1 for Just don't use more than one framework or it'll get messy.

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery when it really isn't needed. Learning "standard" JavaScript is really helpful, even (or especially) when using frameworks...

Comment: By all the answers I figure I will learn Javascript first and will follow it up with JQuery. Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend learning [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), it is a very powerful javascript framework giving you a nice little abstraction over the typical DOM (document object model) manipulations.

I would also give a look to [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), which helps you add smooth animation and effects to you page while giving you the possibility to use nifty features such as tabs and modal dialog boxes.

Comment: +1 javascript + jquery +jquery UI and you have the best tools around

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a javascript library that pretty much eliminates cross-browser javascript issues and makes DHTML stuff (like animations, controlling css effects) spectacularly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Start with learning JavaScript itself before you get to other technologies. It's the underlying layer for most of the others so no harm in knowing it. There are also many non-browser related languages that evolved from the same roots so you'll only benefit from that knowledge.

Further on, when you'll be dealing with some specific problems you may try to see which of the other technologies addresses those problems (like cross-browser compliance) the best and then start learning it. This way you'll make your learning curve smoother, more adequate to your needs and you'll not get demotivated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and JQuery seem to be very strong at the moment, but the answer will change over time to whatever has flavour of the month.